# Why does Buffer from my Observable not receive events?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactivex

I have tried several ways but failing to get my subscription method called:

- Method 1:

  ```
  var buffer = new List<Kpi>();
  buffer.ToObservable().Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 5).Subscribe(
  async kpis =>
  {
      await _retry.ExecuteAsync(() => Process(kpis.ToList())).ConfigureAwait(false);
  });
  ```

  Then `buffer.Add(new Kpi());` won't trigger my method.

---

- Method 2: (Note: I have read the definition for the special methods `Empty/Never/Throw` but other than these I can't seem to find a way to create an observable that emits something other than primitive numbers etc.)

  ```
  var buffer = Observable.Empty<Kpi>();
  buffer.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 5).Subscribe(
  async kpis =>
  {
      await _retry.ExecuteAsync(() => Process(kpis.ToList())).ConfigureAwait(false);
  });
  ```

  Then `buffer.Publish(new Kpi())` . Again nothing happens

**Where am I am going wrong ?**

Comment: Can you add definition of buffer to each snippet? It is unclear what buffer is in the second one.

Comment: @Euphoric Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, calling `ToObservable` on `List` won't make the `List` magically notify of it's changes. List simply does not have that feature.

In the second case, [Publish](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211622(v=vs.103).aspx) does something completely different than what you are expecting.

If you want to create an observable from events, you are looking for [Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229173(v=vs.103).aspx) class.

```
var buffer = new Subject<Kpi>();
buffer.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 5).Subscribe(
async kpis =>
{
    await _retry.ExecuteAsync(() => Process(kpis.ToList())).ConfigureAwait(false);
});

// notify of new item
buffer.OnNext(new Kpi());
```

There are many ways to create [new observable sequence](https://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/16-ways-to-create-iobservables-without-implementing-iobservable). I would recommend read through it to see if one is more suited for you. For example turning event into observable.

Comment: Thanks `OnNext` and `Subject` was what I needed! However, I have read things about avoiding `Subject`. Will it have any disadvantages ?

Comment: @Cemre Subject is low-level primitive. As such, you should be careful in using it. You should always think if there is other way before using Subject as there are valid case to use Subject.

Comment: my 2¢: If you want to create an observable from events, you are *not* looking for Subject class, but `Observable.FromEventPattern`.

Comment: So this leaves the question of; What is it that calls `buffer.OnNext(new Kpi());`? The answer to that will lead you to the replacement of `Subject<T>` usage.

Comment: @LeeCampbell - That's a very good way to think about how to remove the subject. I like it.